# In Vue, setting props default value to computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
  props: {
    rules: {
        type: Array,
        required: false,
        default: () => [
            (file) => !file
                || file.size < 10000000
                || this.getJsonDataByLocale.less_than_10mb_message,
            (file) => !file
                || ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPES.includes(file.type)
                || this.getJsonDataByLocale.wrong_file_message,
        ],
    }
}
```

This is generic component. I'm trying to set rules default to a computed property. 'this.getJsonDataByLocale' is a getter computed property.

It seems to be like as Vue life cycle renders props earlier than the computed property so it doesn't know how to fetch the data from the computed property.

I really need to use 'this.getJsonDataByLocale', as this error msg needs to be a dynamic value.

Anyone can give me some advices?

Comment: I just found out that in props property, 'this' refers to window...
Is there any way I can get 'this' to refer to the component?

Comment: this refers to window because you use an arrow. But it won't refer to component instance any way. Put all this conditional logic into the component, likely another computed

Answer (score 0):

As Vue's official doc says,

> Note that props are validated before a component instance is created, so instance properties (e.g. data, computed, etc.) will not be available inside default or validator functions. [link](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20props%20are%20validated%20before%20a%20component%20instance%20is%20created%2C%20so%20instance%20properties%20(e.g.%20data%2C%20computed%2C%20etc.)%20will%20not%20be%20available%20inside%20default%20or%20validator%20functions.)

So I think we can't access computed property in props

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you simply cannot use computed values in your props. But couldn't you just do it the other way around and use the prop in a computed? Something like this:

```
props: {
    rules: {
        type: Array,
        required: false,
        default: () => []
    }
},
computed: {
    errorMsg() {
        if (!this.rules.length) { // No rules prop data: use default
            return [
                (file) => !file
                    || file.size < 10000000
                    || this.getJsonDataByLocale.less_than_10mb_message,
                (file) => !file
                    || ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPES.includes(file.type)
                    || this.getJsonDataByLocale.wrong_file_message,
            ]
        }
        // We do have rules prop data: use that
        return this.rules;
    }
}
```